# __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'user_id' in django

Tags: python, django

i have a form for update view like this:

```py
class editpost(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Posts
        fields = ['body']
```

and a view like this:

```py
@login_required
def post_edit(request, user_id, post_id):
    if request.user.id == user_id:
        post = get_object_or_404(Post, pk=post_id)
        if request.method == 'POST':
            form = editpost(request.POST, instance=post)
            if form.is_valid():
                ep = form.save(commit=False)
                ep.slug = slugify(form.cleaned_data['body'][:30])
                ep.save()
                messages.success(request, 'your post edited successfully', 'success')
                return redirect('account:dashboard', user_id)
        else:
            form = EditPostForm(instance=post)
        return render(request, 'editpost.html', {'form':form})
    else:
        return redirect('Posts:index')
```

and url.py like this:

```py
from django.urls import path
from . import views
app_name = 'Posts'
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index.as_view(),name='index'),
    path('<int:year>/<int:month>/<int:day>/<slug:slug>', views.detailPost,name='detail'),
    path('addpost/<int:user_id>', views.addpost,name='addpost'),
    path('delpost/<int:user_id>/<int:post_id>', views.delpost,name='delpost'),
    path('editpost/<int:user_id>/<int:post_id>', views.editpost,name='editpost'),
]
```

when i open editpost url i got this error,what should i do to fix it?

Comment: can you include account/urls.py

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The path for editpost should point to your view method: `views.post_edit` not `views.editpost`

```
path('editpost/<int:user_id>/<int:post_id>', views.post_edit, name='editpost'),
```